# Import nested child of JSON file to Postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql, psql

I am trying to import few data from a JSON file. The JSON file is nested and I want to import the child values. The JSO structure is something like this

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "properties": {
        "zoom": 14,
        "x": 12302,
        "y": 7075
    },
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "FeatureCollection",
            "properties": {
                "layer": "poi",
                "version": 3,
                "extent": 4096
            },
            "features": [
                {
                    "type": "Feature",
                    "id": 4356,
                    "properties": {
                        "fid": "eg-34678h765",
                        "name": "Brooklyn Children's Museum"
                    },
                    "geometry": {
                        "type": "Point",
                        "coordinates": [
                            -73.944030,
                            40.674427
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to fetch the following child values (given as like I call this with JS)

```
features[0].features[i].id
features[0].features[i].properties.fid
features[0].features[i].properties.name
features[0].features[i].geometry.coordinates[0]
features[0].features[i].geometry.coordinates[1]
```

into `myTable` entitled columns `id`, `fid`, `name`, `longitude`, `latitude`

I came up with a solution but that only insert the parent values like `type`, `properties`, `features` like this through `psql`

```
copy temp_json from 'E:\myJson.json';

insert into myTable ("type", "properties", "features") 

select values->>'type' as type,
       values->>'properties' as properties,
       values->>'features' as features
from   (
           select json_array_elements(replace(values,'\','\\')::json) as values 
           from   temp_json
       ) a;
```

where `features` inserted as `JSONB`.

How can I get my desired fields from the JSON file and insert into the targetted column of my table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
select j2->>'id' as id,
       j2->'properties'->>'fid'  as fid,
       j2->'properties'->>'name' as name,
       MAX( CASE WHEN l.k = 1 THEN l.cord end ) as longitude,
       MAX( CASE WHEN l.k = 2 THEN l.cord end ) as latitude
       from temp_json 
    cross join json_array_elements(values->'features') as j1
    cross join json_array_elements(j1->'features') as j2
    cross join json_array_elements_text(j2->'geometry'->'coordinates')
                                 with ordinality l(cord,k)
                                 GROUP BY 1,2,3
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=5b0a2ee07ee4e3cfe0bf4cb864ccc2d3)

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) to extract the data in TSV format (for example), and then import it into the database.

The relevant jq filter would be very similar to your preferred format:

```
features[0].features[]
| [.id, .properties.fid, .properties.name, .geometry.coordinates[:2][] ]
| @tsv
```

Since your postgres script is reading from a file anyway, it would probably be simplest
to perform the conversion at the command-line, along the lines of:

```
jq -f totsv.jq E:\myJson.json > myExtract.tsv
```

where totsv.jq holds the jq script above.